# Query Source could not be identified

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I am trying to generate a list of type `Transaction` from a list of type `Posting` by using group by:

```
var transactions = postings
.GroupBy(p => p.TransactionId, (key, g) => new { TransactionId = key, Postings = g })
.Select(x => new Transaction
{
TransactionId = x.TransactionId,
PostingCount = x.Postings.Count(),
TransactionState = x.Postings.First().PostingState,
CreateDate = x.Postings.First().CreateDate,
CreateUser = x.Postings.First().CreateUser
});
```

But I encounter this error:

> **Query Source could not be identified: ItemName = _3, ItemType = Crm.Library.Model.Posting, Expression = from Posting _3 in Convert([p])**

This error happens when I perform any operation on `x.Postings` [`First()` for example].

Any Ideas on how to get the desired result?

Comment: I don't understand you, it seems to work perfectly https://dotnetfiddle.net/r08NzF

Comment: It does not work for me, it outputs that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by converting the list of `Posting` to `IEnumerable` before using `GroupBy`
The problem with using `IQueryable` it will be translated to SQL which will not understand my .net methods. Projections to custom types are part of the query and must be hardcoded.

My code is now:

```
var transactions = postings.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(p => p.TransactionId, (key, g) => new { TransactionId = key, Postings = g })
                .Select(x => new Transaction
                {
                    TransactionId = x.TransactionId,
                    PostingCount = x.Postings.Count(),
                    TransactionState = x.Postings.First().PostingState,
                    CreateDate = x.Postings.First().CreateDate,
                    CreateUser = x.Postings.First().CreateUser
                });
```